# Vagrant up got errors

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

i was installed homestead for laravel 5.4, and yesterday my OS got some problem so i destroyed box , but later when i try to Vagrant up it, i got below errors, what i have done is re-added it by force, since HomeStead7 already there,

```
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v2.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/2.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> box: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 444k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v2.1.0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

but even that, that is not works, as blow you can see, how can i reinstall my box or is there any way to recovery the homesetad7 by vagrant?

```
    λ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.6.3/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:43:in `

join': incompatible character encodings: GBK and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.6.3/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:43:in `create_command_pointer'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.6.3/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:27:in `start'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.6.3/lib/childprocess/windows/process.rb:70:in `launch_process'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.6.3/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:82:in `start'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:141:in `block in execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in safe_chdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:25:in `chdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:25:in `block in safe_chdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:24:in `synchronize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/safe_chdir.rb:24:in `safe_chdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:140:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:22:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:440:in `block in raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:439:in `raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:377:in `block in execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:372:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_5_0.rb:318:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/forwardable.rb:204:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:53:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:227:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:202:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: whats your project folder and do you have any special character in it ?

Comment: nothing special, all english, and i use it for three months works fine.

Comment: reinstalled vagrant but not works.